# Django Template : Combine 2 loops over different lists

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm wondering how I can combine these 2 querysets in my template in order to loop over them.

```
requests = Download.objects.values('pub__age_id').annotate(count=Count('pub__age_id'))

max_download_number = Download.objects.values('pub__age_id').annotate(max_usage=Max('usage'))

context = {'requests': requests, 'max_download_number': max_download_number}
```

In my template :

```
{% for item in requests %}
    {% for element in max_download_number %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.pub__age_id }}</td>
            <td><span class="badge alert-info">{{ item.count }}</span></td>
             <td>{{ element.max_usage }}</td>
             <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It displays wrong loops :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you combine it in the view:

```
requests = Download.objects.values('pub__age_id').annotate(count=Count('pub__age_id')).annotate(max_usage=Max('usage'))
```

and then in the template:

```
<td>{{ item.pub__age_id }}</td>
<td><span class="badge alert-info">{{ item.count }}</span></td>
<td>{{ item.max_usage }}</td>
```

Comment: So simple ! When I work on Django more than 8 hours per day, the afternoon is so hard ... Thank you so much :)

Comment: I know! I often take a walk in the park theater resets my Braun.

Comment: Haha you're right ! Maybe be you can help me just one more time. How could you divide 2 querysets in order to get mathematical result ? I tried with `Cast`but it doesn't work. Maybe I should post this question on Stack ?

Comment: Please do. And ellaborate a bit more on whatever you're trying to do.